# TCL exec syntax with unknown possible wildcard?

Tags: tcl

I have the following line in a TCL script...

```
exec {*}$cmd
```

I understand that `exec` will run the command specified in the string `$cmd`, but cant find any reference to what the `{*}` does.... Can anyone tell me what the `{*}` does please?

I've thought that the `{...}` means that the first item is a group with *no* substitution allowed, so would it be like prefixing the string in `$cmd` with an asterisk... but this makes no sense to me... any ideas guys?

If I write

```
set cmd "ls"
puts {*}$cmd
```

I get

```
ls
```

So the asterisk is not being printed. Put anything else inside the braces and I get an error... possibly some really simple TCL syntax I'm not aware of but would appreciate a pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tcl, `{*}` will enumerate the elements of a list.

For instance, consider:

```
set cmd {$out Stuff}
puts $cmd
# => $out Stuff
puts {*}$cmd
# => can not find channel named "$out"
```

It is documented [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17158).

Basically, the above code is `puts`-ing `{$out Stuff}` in the first case, but it is evaluating `puts $out Stuff` in the second. Of course, if you now have a channel named `$out`, you will have `Stuff` in that channel.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it :)